# Sharepoint Checkbox Hover Text

Tags: 2013, custom-list

I have a Custom List with checkboxes to for one column. The default text which appears when you hover over a checkbox with your cursor seems to be the name of the checkbox. Is there any way to change this individually for each checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may insert the below JavaScript in your NewForm and EditForm pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
$("span.ms-RadioText label:contains('CHECKBOX LABEL1')").parent().find('input').attr('title','HOVER TEXT CONTENT1');
$("span.ms-RadioText label:contains('CHECKBOX LABEL2')").parent().find('input').attr('title','HOVER TEXT CONTENT2');
$("span.ms-RadioText label:contains('CHECKBOX LABEL3')").parent().find('input').attr('title','HOVER TEXT CONTENT3');
$("span.ms-RadioText label:contains('CHECKBOX LABEL4')").parent().find('input').attr('title','HOVER TEXT CONTENT4');
$("span.ms-RadioText label:contains('CHECKBOX LABEL5')").parent().find('input').attr('title','HOVER TEXT CONTENT5');
});
</script>
```

Replace the below tokens in the above code

- CHECKBOX LABEL1 - CHECKBOX LABEL5 : Text that is displayed right to
  the checkbox. (Identifier for each checkbox)
- HOVER TEXT CONTENT1 - HOVER TEXT CONTENT5 : Corresponding content
  that should be displayed on hover

Comment: Getting an error when I add the code to the NewForm.aspx file.
"Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls."

Comment: How did you add the code?

Comment: I just added it at the bottom of the .aspx file

Comment: Try this way. 1. Open your NewForm.aspx page 2. Edit the page 3. Click on Add a webpart 4. add a Script editor webpart 5. paste the script in the script editor webpart

Comment: It pretty much solved my problem, but it only changes the hover text of the checkbox. Is there also a way to change the hover text of the text next to the box?

Comment: Update: Removing the .find('input') part obviously fixed it -.-

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
I did it by creating css document for that particular page (list view).
Class you should look for is named `ms-RadioText` and attribute/field of that class is **Title**.
First change class name as all checkboxes fields are same class so put sufix or prefix to class name exp. `ms-RadioText1st`.

Bellow is printscreen of my example.
[image]

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, I created css file and edited list and called css for it view in sharepoint designer.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how css works :/